# Intellij Spring Boot Run Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to configure the Spring boot run Configuration in Intellij Ultimate Edition 15.0.4. Done the following.

- Click + to create a new Spring boot configuration
- Added Main Class, VM Options, JRE and environment variables.

I couldn't able to find Enable Launch Optimization and Enable JMX agent under Spring Boot Settings? Can anyone please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that feature was added in a later version? your version is almost 3 years old.
Though [this Intellij documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html) shows the VM flags those options add, so if those options are missing because they were added in a later version you may add those flags to your configuration manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looking to enable JMX agent and Launch Optimization. Not sure if I can add those respective commands in VM options. Any suggestions ?